# What is the difference between one to one and many to one mapping in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

What is the difference between one to one and many to one mapping in hibernate?

Comment: @rocker: welcome at Stackoverflow :) After judging how you originally asked the questions here (which is honestly said horrible), I would recommend you to read those two links to improve the quality of your questions (and indirectly thus also those of the answers!! i.e. `qualityOf(question) == qualityOf(answer)` ): http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

to go along with the general definition...

In a relational database structure, one to one mapping would refer to one row (or tuple) in a database pointing to exactly one other row in a database, linked by some mutual column. (most of the time a key of some sort)

In one to many, a column would hold the value that would relate to many rows in another table.